# Telegram bot does not send caption with hyperlink

Tags: php, api, telegram, telegram-bot

My telegram bot does not send hyperlink in caption of photo, video, voice.

It is strange because hyperlink works for plain text.

**Below is my code for the `sendPhoto` method**

```
<?php

    $p1="<a href=google.com>google</a>";
    $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendPhoto?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chat_id."&photo=".$photo."&caption=".urlencode($p1);
    file_get_contents($url);

?>
```

It sends photo currectly and also sends caption but without any hyperlink :(

**Below code is for the `sendMessage` method**

```
<?php

    $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($p1);
    file_get_contents($url);

?>
```

but `sendMessage` works true..

In response of `sendPhoto` I have:

```
<?

"caption_entities":[{"offset":0,"length":5,"type":"text_link","url":"http://google.com/"}

?>
```

How can I fix it?

Is it any configuration in botfather?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rich text in caption is new feature & ONLY last android version of official Telegram (not Mobogram, etc) can display it.

see for example:
[image]
do you see [this post](https://t.me/tg_ir/721) same above picture?

Comment: damet garm dadash :)  update kardam ok shod..faghat y chizi..ro desktop kar nmikoe in hyper link?

Comment: just at last version of official Android. other platform and also unofficial must support this new feature in next months.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the client you are using hasn't support that yet, such as TDesktop.

I have sent [this payload](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?sendPhoto-2cc69c19), and see normal text in Desktop, but have HTML markup in Android client.

Comment: i test it via my android phone and it does not show hyperlink again :(  so i think this is a problem of telegram

Comment: @a.programmer What is your app version?

Comment: last version of telegram desktop

Comment: @a.programmer Please try Android devices, you can forward that to your friends.

Comment: As I mention above, desktop version did not support yet, even alpha (v1.2.8) version.

Comment: Sure, I have send same payload from PHP

Comment: @a.programmer Y